# Convert numbers to symbols without string or char literals

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source

Read infinitely from stdin, and convert every number to the corresponding symbol on a US qwerty keyboard.

No string or character literals anywhere are permitted.

E.g. if the input is `117758326`, the output is `!!&&%*#@^`.

Letters and symbols that aren't on numbers are left alone; `11g2;;'1g2311hh21930` turns into `!!g@;;'!g@#!!hh@!(#)`

Shortest code, in bytes, wins.

For those who don't have a US qwerty keyboard, use the following as a guide:

```
1 -> !
2 -> @
3 -> #
4 -> $
5 -> %
6 -> ^
7 -> &
8 -> *
9 -> (
0 -> )
```

Answer (score 5):

### C, 90 bytes

The line between a character and an integer literal is a very fine one in C.

```
a[]={8,0,31,2,3,4,61,5,9,7};main(d){for(;~(d=getchar());)putchar(d>47&d<58?a[d-48]+33:d);}
```

Comment: shoot, there's a string literal in the printf. fixing later

Comment: `putchar()` - and its 4 bytes shorter too!

Comment: this is 92
`a[]={41,33,64,35,36,37,94,39,42,40};main(d){for(;d=getchar();)putchar(d>47&d<58?a[d-48]:d);}`

Comment: @DigitalTrauma yeah I know, I just didn't think of it right away for some reason and had to leave really quickly then

Comment: @bebe thanks a lot! some neat ideas there. :) I'm not really using C for golfing, usually.

Comment: It's `38` not `39`

Comment: @soktinpk cheers, fixed

Comment: `a[]={8,0,31,2,3,4,61,5,9,7};main(d){for(;d=getchar();)putchar(d>47&d<58‌​?a[d-48]+33:d);}`

Comment: @millinon whoa, huge savings! thanks ;)

Comment: I'm actually getting an error where it doesn't terminate on EOF. EOF is typically -1, so evaluating EOF doesn't yield false.

Comment: @millinon sorry, i read infinitely quite literally. you have to check for eot at getchar if you need an escape code :(

Comment: @bebe When I tested my original code, I didn't get EOF, just new lines.

Comment: If you want to test for EOF, you can use `d>0` instead of `d!=10`. Then newlines will still work, and it'll stop at EOF or a null byte.

Comment: @millinon Yeah I just tried actual console input instead of STDIN redirection, and PowerShell doesn't send EOF. But I guess that would be a fair assumption.

Comment: a bit late but... `...for(;~(d=getchar());)...` 90!

Comment: @bebe cheers! ^^

Answer (score 3):

### Perl - <strike>74</strike> <strike>57</strike> 42

Update thanks to core1024's comment:

```
s/\d/chr 33+(8,0,31,2..4,61,5,9,7)[$&]/eg
```

Run with:

```
perl -p program_name.pl
```

---

Update thanks to manatwork's comment:

```
say s/\d/chr@{[8,0,31,2,3,4,61,5,9,7]}[$&]+33/erg while<>
```

Test with:

```
perl -E 'say s/\d/chr@{[8,0,31,2,3,4,61,5,9,7]}[$&]+33/erg while<>'
```

---

Old attempts:

```
say s/[1234567890]/chr qw(41 33 64 35 36 37 94 38 42 40)[$&]/erg while(<>)
```

Using `qw` counts as a string literal though.

Test:

```
perl -E 'say s/[1234567890]/chr qw(41 33 64 35 36 37 94 38 42 40)[$&]/erg while(<>)'
```

Another way: Perl 40 - I think this counts as a string literal as well.

```
say tr/1234567890/!@#$%^&*()/r while(<>)
```

Test with:

```
perl -E 'say tr/1234567890/!@#$%^&*()/r while(<>)'
```

Comment: Are you sure that isn't a string literal? `!@#$%^&*()` sure looks like one.

Comment: @isaacg I didn't read the question closely enough and I think you're right. I updated with another solution.

Comment: As documentation describes `qw//` as “quote a list of words”, in my interpretation there you have 10 string literals. So I suggest to change it into array of integers (`@{[41,33,…]}` or something better) (no change in code size); leave off the parenthesis around the statement modifier's expression (2 characters shorter); subtract 33 from all character codes and add it separately (3 characters shorter); replace character class with `\d` wildcard (10 characters shorter): `say s/\d/chr(@{[8,0,31,2,3,4,61,5,9,7]}[$&]+33)/erg while<>`.

Comment: @manatwork thanks! nice work! I updated the answer. Also you can take the parenthesis out of `chr(...)`.

Comment: You can use the `-p` flag to drop the `while`, `say` and the `r` RegEx modifier from your code. You can also save more bytes by using `33+(31,2..4,61)[]` instead of `@{[31,2,3,4,61]}[]+33`.

Comment: You count your code's bytes +1 for the `p` flag. Try to save this in a text file with shebang like `#!/usr/bin/perl -p` or just `perl -p file.pl`.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6) - <del>79</del> <del>76</del> 87

*Edit* - bloated out by 11 chars after it was pointed out that it failed the "non-numbers are left alone" rule (thanks @soktinpk)

*Warning* - you'll need to reload your browser after you run it since it's following the "Read infinitely from stdin" bit...

```
(f=x=>f(alert(+(p=prompt())+1?String.fromCharCode([8,0,31,2,3,4,61,5,9,7][p]+33):p)))()
```

Note that I've interpreted `prompt` as `stdin` & `alert` as `stdout`

Tested in Firefox console.

Comment: Wouldn't you have to iterate over it? The input is not guaranteed to be one digit...

Comment: Also, this doesn't satisfy the rule _characters which aren't digits should be left alone._

Comment: @soktinpk - on your first point, it loops indefinitely by recursively calling itself (it's an interpretation of how to indefinitely read from stdin in javascript... the implication of the question is that it should process each character as it comes in, which is effectively what I'm doing, via a prompt). Your second point is spot on though, I missed that... will have to revisit the code...

Comment: @soktinpk - fixed now - but it cost me 11 characters. Curse you! :P

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 43

```
W1sm?C+33@[8Z31 2 3 4 61 5tT7)vd}Cdr48 58dw
```

Uses 33+table lookup, instead of straight table lookup. No translate function here, just a normal map. Note that Z=0 and tT=9.

Answer (score 1):

### Scala, 106 bytes

```scala
def f{println(readLine.map{c=>try{(Seq(8,0,31,2,3,4,61,5,9,7)(c.toInt-48)+33).toChar}catch{case _=>c}});f}
```

Pretty-printed:

```scala
def f {
  println(readLine.map { c =>
    try {
      (Seq(8,0,31,2,3,4,61,5,9,7)(c.toInt - 48) + 33).toChar
    } catch {
      case _ => c
    }
  })
  f
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [pyg-i](https://gist.github.com/ids1024/8c3c3a0653566ada4149) (68)

Here is a solution in pyg-i, a fork of pyg I created:

```
while 1:P(Ip().t(dict(Z(R(48,58),(41,33,64,35,36,37,94,38,42,40)))))
```

The python 3 equivalent would be this:

```
while 1:print(input().translate(dict(zip(range(48,58),(41,33,64,35,36,37,94,38,42,40)))))
```

Or, with a little cheating, it can be done in 50 bytes.  Note that this is a *bytes* literal, not a string literal:

```
while 1:P(Ip().t(dict(Z(R(48,58),b"(!@#$%^&*("))))
```

Answer (score 0):

## CoffeeScript (70)

**Update**: This may be seen as reading between the lines, but while strings and characters aren't allowed, regexs are. (I just converted the regex to a string).

```
alert prompt().replace /\d/g, (t)->([]+/!@#$%^&*()/)[1...-1][(+t+9)%10]
```

Or (for infinite)

```
loop alert prompt().replace /\d/g, (t)->([]+/!@#$%^&*()/)[1...-1][(+t+9)%10]
```

The normal version (in case regex isn't allowed):

```
alert prompt().replace(/\d/g, (t) ->String.fromCharCode(([]+4133643536+3794384240).match(/\d{2}/g)[t]))
```

Test it out [here](http://coffeescript.org).

But, according to the problem statement,

> Read **infinitely** from stdin

That will probably hang your browser eventually, but here it is (just prepend `loop`, extra 5 bytes, to the code):

```
loop alert prompt().replace(/\d/g, (t) ->String.fromCharCode(([]+4133643536+3794384240).match(/\d{2}/g)[t]))
```

Comment: Looks like you used a string literal.

Comment: @isaacg Updated, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

## Befunge 98 - 119 bytes

This is also with the STRN fingerprint, that allows "S" to stand for a ***convert integer to string*** instruction.

```
v>0 NRTS 4( >&S v         >$a,v
5 )!@#$%^&*(    >:1       w1  v
7^       p<     ^,g1--3*77< 
>*1-:30p80^ ^                 <
```

Answer (score 0):

**Haskell, 89**

```
f 50=64
f 54=94
f 55=38
f 56=42
f 57=40
f 48=41
f x|x<48||x>57=x|0<1=x-16
g=map$chr.f.ord
```

tests:

Prelude> g "11g2;;'1g2311hh21930"

"!!g@;;'!g@#!!hh@!(#)"

Prelude> g "117758326"

"!!&&%*#@^"

Answer (score 0):

## CJam - 32

```
qA,s26063649909601297730 95b:cer
```

Try it at http://cjam.aditsu.net/

**Explanation:**

`q` reads the whole input
`A,` creates the array [0 1 ... 9] (A=10)
`s` converts to string, obtaining "0123456789"
`95b` converts the previous big number to an array of base-95 digits, which are the ASCII codes of the 10 symbols we want
`:c` converts the ASCII codes to characters, obtaining the string `")!@#$%^&*("`
`er` transliterates "0123456789" to ")!@#$%^&*(" in the input string

Answer (score 0):

## tcl, 156

```
proc x n {format %c $n}
while 1 {puts [string map "1 [x 33] 2 [x 64] 3 [x 35] 4 [x 36] 5 [x 37] 6 [x 94] 7 [x 38] 8 [x 36] 9 [x 40] 0 [x 41]" [gets stdin]]}
```

testable on http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_tcl_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMRE4tMlc3cmJhNG8

Answer (score -1):

**PYTHON: <strike>166</strike> 86**

Not better than the current answers, but the shortest Python solution I can think of as of yet.

(thanks to pseudonym117 for helping me shorten this significantly)

```
def g(s):
 d=')!@#$%^&*('
 g=''
 for c in s:
  try:g+=d[int(c)]
  except:g+=c
 yield g
```

Comment: `d=')!@#$%^&*('` is way shorter, though it uses string literals. your original answer does too though

Comment: Whoops, definitely grazed right over that limitation. I'll leave this one up anyway, and take your suggestion which for some reason I totally didn't think of.

Comment: also `w=int(c)` seems to not do anything at all, and `g+=d[c]` would need to be changed to `g+=d[int(c)]`

Comment: w=int(c) is to catch anything that isn't a number that may be in the string. int() raises an exception if it isn't passed a proper integer.

Comment: ah. still, combining the 2 lines into 1 would work identically.